# Azure Service Mgmt Api configuration change (400 Bad request error)

Tags: c#, api, post, configuration, azure

i am trying to upload a configuration file using the azure management api. I am getting a 400 bad request error and i cannot figure out why, any suggestions?

Here is the API doc for the change configuration operation.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/ee460809.aspx

And here is my code. Any responces greatly appreciated

```
 public void changeConfiguration(string serviceName, string deploymentSlot, string config, string deploymentName)
    {
        byte[] encodedConfigbyte = new byte[config.Length];
        encodedConfigbyte = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(config);
        string temp = Convert.ToBase64String(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(config));

        Uri changeConfigRequestUri = new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/" + subscriptionId + "/services/hostedservices/" + serviceName + "/deploymentslots/" + deploymentName + "/?comp=config");

        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(changeConfigRequestUri);
        request.Headers.Add("x-ms-version", "2010-10-28");
        request.Method = "POST";

        string bodyText = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                          "<ChangeConfiguration  xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\"" + ">"
                          + "<Configuration>" + temp + "</Configuration>              </ChangeConfiguration>";

        byte[] buf = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(bodyText);
        request.ContentType = "application/xml";
        request.ContentLength = buf.Length;

        X509Store certStore = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
        try
        {
            certStore.Open(OpenFlags.ReadOnly);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            if (e is CryptographicException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: The store is unreadable.");
            }
            else if (e is SecurityException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: You don't have the required permission.");
            }
            else if (e is ArgumentException)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Error: Invalid values in the store.");
            }
            else
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
        X509Certificate2Collection certCollection = certStore.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindByThumbprint, thumbprint, false);
        certStore.Close();
        if (certCollection.Count == 0)
        {
            throw new Exception("Error: No certificate found containing thumbprint ");
        }
        X509Certificate2 certificate = certCollection[0];
        request.ClientCertificates.Add(certificate);
        Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();

        dataStream.Write(buf, 0, buf.Length);

        dataStream.Close();

            //Error occurs in the line below
            WebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is there no body to the response from the server?

It looks like when you're constructing your URL, you're using "deploymentName" where you want "deploymentSlot." Could that be it?

Comment: Thanks for the reply,I amnt sure about the body to the response but the documentation says i can use either deployment name or deployment slot

Comment: But if you use the deployment name, then the URL needs to look like this: `https://management.core.windows.net/<subscription-id>/services/hostedservices/<service-name>/deployments/<deployment-name>/?comp=config` Your URL looks like the one which uses the deployment slot.

Comment: Well spotted, you were right, i did have the wrong URL, however i have changed it to 

`Uri changeConfigRequestUri = new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/" + subscriptionId + "/services/hostedservices/" + serviceName + "/deployments/" + deploymentName + "/?comp=config");`
            
and i am still getting the 400 bad request error

Comment: Are you sure the "deploymentName" is right? (I don't believe the portal will show you the deployment name... I think it's a GUID if you created the deployment via the portal.) I think the body of the 400 response would be helpful. Catch the exception and read the response.

Comment: You were right about the deployment name, i was putting in the id, i hard coded the proper name but i am still get the 400 bad request, and the exception response doesnt give me any new information

Comment: It says "System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request." And when i examine the response its the exact same as the request but with the status code changed to "Bad Request"

Comment: I think you should be able to do something like `catch (WebException e) { Console.WriteLine(new StreamReader(e.Response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd()); }` to read the full body of the response.

Comment: I tried that and i get ""<Error xmlns=\"http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure\" xmlns:i=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\"><Code>BadRequest</Code><Message>No change in settings specified</Message></Error>""

Comment: Is it accurate? (Are you not making any change in the config?)

Comment: I am, I change the instance count in the configuration file from 1 to 2, i checked the config file after i changed it and it did change the instance count from 1 to 2